# Ansible combine 'setup' output with task output to JSON

Tags: ansible

I currently gather facts about all my hosts using this command:

```
 ansible all -m setup --tree out
```

This creates a file for each host in the directory `out` with all the ansible variables in JSON format. Very useful.

However, my hosts consist of a lot of KVM hosts, so I want to add the output of `virt` / `list_vms` to each output.

I created a small playbook:

```
hosts: myhost

tasks:
  - name: VM list checker
    virt:
        name: list the VMs
        command: list_vms
```

I run this playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -v status.playbook.yml -s
```

I would like the output to be in `JSON` format, preferably combining the `facts` and the output of the `list_vms`.

How can I create a similar layout (one `JSON` per host in the `out` directory?) with the combined information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the input from @KonstantinSuvorov I came up with this:

```
---
- hosts: kvm_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - setup:
      register: setup_res
    - virt: "command=list_vms"
      register: cmd_res
    - copy:
        content: "{{ setup_res | combine(cmd_res) | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/out/{{ inventory_hostname }}.json
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - setup:
      register: setup_res
    - command: echo ok
      register: cmd_res
    - file:
        path: /tmp/out/{{ inventory_hostname }}
        state: directory
      delegate_to: localhost
    - copy:
        content: "{{ setup_res | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/out/{{ inventory_hostname }}/facts.json
      delegate_to: localhost
    - copy:
        content: "{{ cmd_res | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/out/{{ inventory_hostname }}/cmd.json
      delegate_to: localhost
```

replace `command` call with `virt`.

Comment: This is a great start! Thank you, I will read more about the `register` option.